# Counting fully downloaded files

Tags: php, apache, nginx, download

Is it possible to count only fully file downloads (when user click accept when save dialog apparents) using nginx or apache (php on backend, but nginx deliver files)?

Comment: See also: https://dave.autonoma.ca/blog/2023/11/12/php-download-hit-counter/

Answer (score 2):

A pure PHP solution could look like this (simplified):

```
<?php

$file = $_GET['file'];
check_if_file_is_ok_for_download($file);

header('Content-Type: ...');
header('Content-Length: ...');
header('Content-Dispostion: ...'); 
// more headers if necesarry ...

// output the file
readfile($file);

// count the finished download
database_add_finished_download($file);
```

Then use download links like:

```
http://yourserver.com/download.php?file=...
```

Which can be url-rewritten to something like:

```
http://yourserver.com/download/...
```

Comment: thanks!This solution is really simple, but php delivering files get much memory. Any suggestions for server solution?

Comment: We used this on an video server server, serving >5GB files in a high-load environment. no memory problems. The script will **not** consume as much memory as the file size of the downloaded file.

Comment: Really, according to [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) using this function won't get any memory issues.

Comment: yep, otherwise it would have been poorly designed. I would use this. Beside from just counting the download you are able to collect other information. Also you are able to generate or manipulate downloadable content dynamically.

Comment: @dzubchik But you should note one additional thing: When it comes to large downloads, the possibility of pausing and resuming downloads is important for clients. `readfile()` will not suffer in this case as you cannot specify a byte-offset. If you want to support pause/resume then get the byte offset from http headers and then use `fopen(), fseek(), fread() and echo` with a proper buffersize. This would be the *best* solution-